# DataGrid cannot save the data by paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Following is ASPX code:

```
<asp:datagrid id="gridcontestant" runat="server" CssClass="grd_standard"
DataKeyField="ASSIGNMENT_ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" BorderStyle="None" tabIndex="-1"
onpageindexchanged="gridcontestant_PageIndexChanged" PageSize="3">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ASSIGNMENT_CONTESTANT" HeaderText="Contestant ID"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CONTESTANT_NAME" HeaderText="Contestant Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="50px"/>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle CssClass="grd_ps_standard" Mode="NumericPages"/>
</asp:datagrid>
```

All the data have checked is need to save into database, but I having issue on DataGrid when I click save button is just save first page only.

Following is C# code:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridItemCollection items;
    CheckBox cb;
    items = gridcontestant.Items;
    for(var i = 0; i <= items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        cb = ((CheckBox)(items[i].FindControl("chk")));
        if(cb.Checked)
        {
            objDBInterface.masterTable = "QUESTION_ASSIGNMENT_JUDGE";
            objDBInterface.primaryField = "JUDGE_ID";
            objDBInterface.strConn = mag.ConnStr();

            string newIDJudge = objDBInterface.getNewCode();

            objDBInterface.ExecSQL("INSERT INTO QUESTION_ASSIGNMENT_JUDGE VALUES ('"
                                    + newIDJudge + "', '"
                                    + mag.ADOQuoteField(items[i].Cells[7].Text) + "', '"
                                    + item + "', '"
                                    + Session["varSegID"].ToString() + "', 'N', NULL, NULL, 'N', NULL, 'F')");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's right!

If you start from Datagrid items, you will have only current bound page.

You have to save in ViewState checked data on every Postback (also when you change page).

If the number of records is not too high you can disable the pagination on datagrid.